# Возможно ли реализовать авторизацию на сайте, без использования Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, global-variables

У меня есть пет проект, на котором я решил добавить авторизацию, только недавно начал изучать Reactjs и еще при попытке реализовать авторизацию столкнулся с проблемой, что после авторизации если воспользоваться роутингом, то сайт теряет информацию о авторизации и требует регистрацию по новой, прошерстив гугл узнал, что это обходится Redux'ом или Context'ом, но при попытке интегрировать Redux у меня возникло куча вопросов, а Context не получается изменить в дочернем компоненте, так вот, есть ли варианты попроще создать глобальную переменную, которая будет доступна в любой точке сайта? А то добавлять довольно громоздкую библиотеку ради двух строк не совсем хочется.

Comment: а что с контекстом не так?

Comment: Я не могу найти нормального объяснения, как его изменять из чилдрена, его же надо задавать в верховном компоненте, по типу Index или App, из которых обычно всё начинается и юзать Provider, но как изменять значения внутри я нигде не нашёл, если сможете, сделайте какую-нибудь вакуумную версию, где вы сначала задаёте пустой контекст сверху, а потом изменяете его через 2 уровня внизу, буду очень благодарен @entithat

Comment: @entithat Если вам не хочется делать, сообщите мне, я попробую сам, а вы добавите правки, какие нужно внести, чтобы контекст можно было изменить из дочернего компонента

Comment: Ну вот вы добавили провайдер в `App.js` и в этот провайдер надо добавлять еще пропс `value={...}` сам контекст, (который вы создали) и теперь в дочерних элементах просто использовать хук useContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример использования контекста. И не надо никаких редаксов. Добавил компоненты `A` и `B` для наглядности вложенности.

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false
};
```

Создаем контекст с начальным значением `initialState`. Далее этот контекст мы будем использовать в хуке `useContext`.

```
export const UserContext = createContext(initialState);

export function A() {
  return <B />;
}

export function B() {
  return <C />;
}

export function C() {
  const { userState, setUserState } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setUserState((p) => ({ ...p, isLoggedIn: !p.isLoggedIn }))
        }
      >
        {!userState.isLoggedIn ? "Log in" : "Log out"}
      </button>
      <p>User is {!userState.isLoggedIn && "not"} logged in</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

В родительском компоненте создаем провайдер и передаем значение `userState, setUserState` в пропс `value`. Далее мы будем их использовать в наших дочерних компонентах.

```
export default function App() {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initialState);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ userState, setUserState }}>
      <A />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cerf-47b4c?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123743/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat-------).